# Add Google search in web page

Tags: html, search

I'd like to add search to a static site. The simplest way is to simply query Google by appending "site:www.acme.com" to the actual query so that Google will limit search to that site.

Ideally, I'd like to do this in the browser, to avoid having to install PHP on the server. Using a form, I don't know how to append the search items:

```
<form action=http://www.google.com?q="site:www.acme.com+...">
<input type=text id=search_item>
</form>
```

Does someone know of a client-side solution? Should I use some JavaScript for this?

Thank you.

---

Edit: When using "method=get" and "input name=q value="site:www.acme.com "", the browser will indeed call Google with "www.google.com?q="site:www.acme.com some item", but I'd rather avoid presetting the input box with "site:www.acme.com" because users will find this odd and might remove it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You just need to set the form method to "get", add one extra hidden element with the site you want to search and it will automatically paste it behind the URL as such:

```
<form action="https://google.com/search" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="http://acme.com" />
<input type="text" name="q" />
</form>
```

Because that is how HTML forms work by default.

Comment: "You just need to set the form method to "get"" — That isn't needed. GET is the default method.

Comment: I added it explicitly (about five years ago) to make sure it's clear because this might not work when posting.

Comment: I tried this but not working. <form action="https://google.com/search" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="http://emoncmt2.byethost15.com/Digital" />
    <input type="text" name="q" />
   </form>

Answer (score 0):

u can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function google_search()
{
window.location = "http://www.google.com/search?q=site:www.acme.com+" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("q").value);
}

</script>

<form onSubmit="google_search()">
<input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="search" onClick="return google_search()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. RR's solution works without using JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

```html
  <form method="get" action="http://google.com/search">
    
    <input type="text" name="q" required autofocus>
    <input type="submit" value="Google search">
  
  </form>
```

**If you want to use Bing Search engine then replace 'google' with 'bing'.**

Comment: That searches the whole WWW. The question is about searching a specific site.