# How do we set up the attributes on the form and input tags to get the "I'm Feeling Lucky" search to work (no javascript)?

Tags: html, forms, url, search, input

For project 0 of the Edx.org CS50’s Web Programming with Python and JavaScript , one of the tasks is to create a search feature that will allow the user to perform advanced google searches and the "I'm feeling lucky" submit button.
Before getting into the Google advanced search, which is more challenging, the "I'm feeling lucky" submission is supposed to send a http get request url that only returns the first item resulting from the search.  Google has discontinued this feature and the lecture does not cover this, but from the research I have [gathered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178344/passing-html-form-values-to-google-search-query) I have found that the following URL, when typed into the address bar of Google Chrome does accomplish the task.

[http://www.google.com/search?q={query}&btnI](http://www.google.com/search?q=%7Bquery%7D&btnI)

or   [https://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q={query}](https://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=%7Bquery%7D)

I am not familiar wıth how to set up the Get request URLs above  using just the HTML Form and Input tags.  There is nothing in the associated lecture that covers this and scripting was not presented yet.  I have tried various ways in setting the attributes for the Form and Input tags, but when applied, the result is just a regular Google search for the  q={query}.  Below is a sample that I have tried.

```
   <form action="https://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q">

    <input type="text" class="search" name="q" style="width:300px"/>
    <input type="submit" class="input_rel_lucky" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" />

</form>
```

The result is just a regular google search.  I have tried ‘type = url’ and typed the URL on the form exactly as the ones that worked on the address bar.  I am probably missing something simple but I have expended too much time already trying to get it to work.

How do we set up the attributes on the form and input tags to get the   "I'm Feeling Lucky" search to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to this

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search">

    <input type="text" class="search" name="q" style="width:300px"/>
    <input type="submit" class="input_rel_lucky" name="btnI" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" />
    
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Thumbs up, it worked:)  So I gather that I would present a seperate input tag for each parameter in the url; is that correct?  Also I noticed you didn't put a question mark after the 'search' in the form action.  What purpose would the question mark serve?

Comment: Sorry my late reply, about the parameters you are correct and the url is because the parameters will be automatically there when you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to fabio-assuncao and to add more:
for google server GET method what that matters is names of submit elements and the input text value. for Google search button default google name is btnK and for I'm Feeling Lucky is btnI. Also, it's good to know to force google to redirect search result for I'm Feeling Lucky option to the first result it is sufficient to name its submit name as btnI,as told before. To prevent empty Google Search from submission that leads to https://www.google.com/wbhp, I wrote the below JS to perform it and it worked out.
To add more about get into google image results, in google image search page you should add an hidden input element with the name of tbm and value of isch.

```js
      <script>
        function submitForm(event) {
          var searchBox = document.getElementById('search-box');
          var inputValue = event.submitter.value;
          if (inputValue === 'Google Search' && searchBox.value.trim() === '') {
              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form empty search submission
            }
        }
      </script>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Search</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <span>
            <a href="templates/image_search.html">Google Image Search</a>
            <a href="templates/advanced_search.html">Google Advanced Search</a>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="search-container" name="searchdiv">
        <form action="https://www.google.com/search" name="searchform" method="GET" onsubmit="submitForm(event)">  
          <input type="text" id="search-box" name="q">
          <br>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" id="search-sub" name="btnK" value="Google Search">
            <input type="submit" class="input_rel_lucky" name="btnI" value="I'm Feeling Lucky"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```js
<script>
    function submitForm(event) {
      var searchBox = document.getElementById('search-box');
      if (searchBox.value.trim() === '') {
          event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form empty search submission
        }
    }
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Images Search</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <div>
    <span>
        <a href="../index.html">Google Search</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="search-container" name="searchdiv">
    <form action="https://www.google.com/search" name="searchform" method="GET" onsubmit="submitForm(event)">  
      <input type="text" id="search-box" name="q">
      <br>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" id="search-sub" value="Google Image Search">
        <input type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```